# Remove ugly white shadow from button when hovered

Tags: html, css, button, shadow

Whenever I hover over my button that I created, it has a white which looks ugly in the transition. I need help to remove this.

The button has two different blocks of css: one for the button itself and other block is `.morb_button` for the same button on a different webpage.

```
button {
      background-color: #961a75;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 25px;
      border:none;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #323d73;
      cursor:pointer;
      transition-duration: 0.2s;
      font-family: Gill Sans
}

button:hover {
      background-color: #cc5caf; 
      color: white;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px
}

.morb_button {
      background-color:#022b27;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #4a0404
}

.morb_button:hover {
      background-color: #03524a;
}
```

Comment: Kindly provide your `HTML` along with your question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the property `box-shadow` twice in the snippet. Remove either of them to fix this.

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px; 
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #4a0404;
```

Comment: Yes, but I wanted the button on one page to have a different color. Should I do separate css for the buttons on both pages perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this rule, because it's the one that gives the white shadow to the button.

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #4a0404;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).